# Json update every x seconds SetInterval

Tags: jquery, json

I made this script to get some json information:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: true,
      timeout: 30000,
      success: function(data) {

            // $('#output ul').append('<li>The feed loads fine');
            $('#output ul').empty();

            $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){ 

                $('#output ul').append('<li><a href="'+data.image+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+data.image+'" alt="" /></a><h3>'+data.title+'</h3><p>'+data.text+'</p></li>');


            });

        },
        error: function(){
            $('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
        }
    });
 });
```

But i want to update the feed every x seconds. I read a lot about it but i can get it done.

How can i do this?

Comment: And what is the problem with setInterval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to repeated call the code block, and put your code in some function and pass the function name to `setInterval` first parameter. You can pass anonymous function instead of making a new function like `repeatMe` but I would prefer making function to make the code more readable.

```
function repeatMe(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  success: function(data) {

        // $('#output ul').append('<li>The feed loads fine');
        $('#output ul').empty();

        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){ 

            $('#output ul').append('<li><a href="'+data.image+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+data.image+'" alt="" /></a><h3>'+data.title+'</h3><p>'+data.text+'</p></li>');


        });
    },
    error: function(){
        $('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
    }
 });
}

setInterval(repeatMe, 5000);
```

**Edit** It would be better to use setTimeout instead of setInterval in the success to send the next call for update after the first has finished its job. We will also put setTimeout in error to keep the repetive call for update.

```
function repeatMe(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  success: function(data) {
        // $('#output ul').append('<li>The feed loads fine');
        $('#output ul').empty();
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){ 

            $('#output ul').append('<li><a href="'+data.image+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+data.image+'" alt="" /></a><h3>'+data.title+'</h3><p>'+data.text+'</p></li>');
            setTimeout(repeatMe, 5000);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        $('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
        setTimeout(repeatMe, 5000);
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be better to set a timeout inside the **success** setting so that the function is called 30 seconds after it succeeded??

Comment: Then we should use setTimeout, as calling setInterval in success again and again will multiply the frequency of call of setInterval function.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I said "set a timeout" :) Of course it depends on what the user wants.

Comment: You forgot to change **setInterval** into **setTimeout**. Also, in the **success** setting I think it would be better to put the setTimout outside of the **$.each()**.

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: true,
      timeout: 30000,
      success: function(data) {

            // $('#output ul').append('<li>The feed loads fine');
            $('#output ul').empty();

            $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){ 

                $('#output ul').append('<li><a href="'+data.image+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+data.image+'" alt="" /></a><h3>'+data.title+'</h3><p>'+data.text+'</p></li>');


            });

        },
        error: function(){
            $('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
        }
    });
    setTimeout(foo, 3000);
}

foo();
```

3000 is the milliseconds you want to wait before calling the function again.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){

  $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: true,
      success: function(data) {

            // $('#output ul').append('<li>The feed loads fine');
            $('#output ul').empty();

            $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){ 

                $('#output ul').append('<li><a href="'+data.image+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+data.image+'" alt="" /></a><h3>'+data.title+'</h3><p>'+data.text+'</p></li>');


            });

        },
        error: function(){
            $('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
        }
    });

},30000);  //30000 == 30 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
       $.ajax({
         url: 'url',
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: true,
         timeout: 30000,
         success: function(data) {    
            // $('#output ul').append('<li>The feed loads fine');
            $('#output ul').empty();

            $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){ 

                $('#output ul').append('<li><a href="'+data.image+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+data.image+'" alt="" /></a><h3>'+data.title+'</h3><p>'+data.text+'</p></li>');


            });

           },
            error: function(){
               $('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
           }
        });
    }, 1000 * x);
 });
```

Above code should work fine. Just put required number of seconds instead of x here: `1000 *x`

Just remember that you should pass a pointer to a function into setInterval as a first parameter. if you do simply `setInterval($.ajax({...}), x)` you actually say that function returned by $.ajax should be executed each x seconds. But it returns jQuery object, not a function. That is why in my code ajax is wrapped with `function() {}`